# Watson Discovery crawler: Couldn't load JDBC driver

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I’m trying to setup a local mongodb crawler for my Watson discovery service. MongoDB is up and running. I downloaded the JDBC connector (mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar) and placed it in /opt/ibm/crawler/connectorFramework/crawler-connector-framework-0.1.18/lib/java/database/

Let me show you how I modified the configuration files:

On crawler.conf, under the main section “input_adapter” I changed the following values:

```
crawl_config_file = "connectors/database.conf",
crawl_seed_file = "seeds/database-seed.conf",
extra_jars_dir = "database",
```

On seeds/database-seed.conf, in the seed > attribute section, the portion of the url looks like this:

```
{
  name ="url",
  value="mongo://localhost:27017/local/tweets?per=1000"
},
```

(tried also using mongodb instead of mongo)

On connectors/database.conf, the first portion of the file looks like this:

```
crawl_extender {
  attribute = [
    {
      name="protocol",
      value="mongo"
    },
    {
      name="collection",
      value="SomeCollection"
    }
  ],
```

(also tried using mongodb instead of mongo)

When I run the crawler command, this is my output:

```
pish@ubuntu-crawler:~$ crawler crawl --config ./crawler-config/config/crawler.conf 
2017-08-02 04:29:10,206 INFO: Connector Framework service will start and connect to crawler on port 35775
2017-08-02 04:29:10,460 INFO: This crawl is running in CrawlRun mode
2017-08-02 04:29:10,460 INFO: Running a crawl...
2017-08-02 04:29:10,465 INFO: URLs matching these patterns will be not be processed: (?i)\.(xlsx?|pptx?|jpe?g|gif|png|mp3|tiff)$
2017-08-02 04:29:10,500 INFO: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2017-08-02 04:29:10,685 INFO: HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2017-08-02 04:29:12,161 ERROR: There was a problem processing URL mongo://localhost:27017/local/tweets?per=1000: Couldn't load JDBC driver : 
2017-08-02 04:29:17,184 INFO: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2017-08-02 04:29:17,196 INFO: HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2017-08-02 04:29:17,198 INFO: The service for the Connector Framework Input Adapter was signaled to halt.
Attempting to shutdown the crawler cleanly.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong in my crawler?

Comment: It looks like you need a JDBC 3.0 compliant driver for MongoDB to [connect your data repository to crawl per IBM](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/data-crawler-seeds.html#configuring-database-crawl-options). You can try the [commercial MongoDB JDBC](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/mongodb) driver from DataDirect which was certified by MongoDB. Note that I am employed by Progress.

Comment: For the sake of a test, I tried with MySQL and its connector compliant with JDBC 3.0 and the same error happens. I don't know why the crawler can't load a different JDBC driver other than the one it bundles and I can't find enough documentation on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, turns out that I also had to specify the connection string in one of the configuration files. It works now.